# Array iteration inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, methods

I need to write a function that will go through all array objects and check wether **at least one object** has inner array where all objects have boolean value set to true. Please see code examples for better understanding.

**Example 1**

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    innerArray: [
      { innerId: 1, clicked: false },
      { innerId: 2, clicked: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    innerArray: [
      { innerId: 1, clicked: true },
      { innerId: 2, clicked: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    innerArray: [
      { innerId: 1, clicked: true },
      { innerId: 2, clicked: true }, 
    ],
  },
];

functionToBeCreated(array); // Output: true - because item with id 3 has innerArray where all items have "clicked: true".
```

**Example 2**

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    innerArray: [
      { innerId: 1, clicked: false },
      { innerId: 2, clicked: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    innerArray: [
      { innerId: 1, clicked: true },
      { innerId: 2, clicked: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    innerArray: [
      { innerId: 1, clicked: false },
      { innerId: 2, clicked: true }, 
    ],
  },
];

functionToBeCreated(array); // Output: false - because no item has innerArray where all items have "clicked: true".
```

Do you have maybe any ideas how it ca be achieved?

Comment: Take a look at [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: and [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Irritation with iteration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way...

```js
const ToBeCreated = arr =>
   arr.some( el => el.innerArray.every(z => z.clicked));

const arrayTRUE = 
  [ { id: 1, innerArray: 
      [ { innerId: 1, clicked: false } 
      , { innerId: 2, clicked: false }
      ] } 
  , { id: 2, innerArray: 
      [ { innerId: 1, clicked: true  } 
      , { innerId: 2, clicked: false } 
    ] } 
  , { id: 3, innerArray: 
      [ { innerId: 1, clicked: true } 
      , { innerId: 2, clicked: true } 
  ] } ] 

const arrayFALSE = 
  [ { id: 1, innerArray: 
      [ { innerId: 1, clicked: false } 
      , { innerId: 2, clicked: false }
      ] } 
  , { id: 2, innerArray: 
      [ { innerId: 1, clicked: true  } 
      , { innerId: 2, clicked: false } 
    ] } 
  , { id: 3, innerArray: 
      [ { innerId: 1, clicked: false } 
      , { innerId: 2, clicked: true  } 
  ] } ] 

// test 
console.log( ToBeCreated(arrayTRUE ) ) 
console.log( ToBeCreated(arrayFALSE) )
```