# JS - compare 2 arrays by key, return 4 arrays: matches & unmatches from each

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, key

Interface -

```
interface I {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    city: string;
    address?: string;
}
```

Arrays -

```
const arr1: I[] = [
  {
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: 'NYC'
  },
  {
    name: "kosta",
    age: 28,
    city: "NYC"
  },
  {
    name: "yoav",
    age: 28,
    city: "NYC"
  }
];

const arr2: I[] = [{
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: "NYC",
    address: 'E. 43'
  },
  {
    name: "simon",
    age: 24,
    city: "NYC",
    address: 'E. 43'
  },
  {
    name: "david",
    age: 22,
    city: "NYC",
    address: 'E. 43'
  },
  {
    name: "kosta",
    age: 28,
    city: "NYC",
    address: 'E. 43'
  }
];
```

Getting keys for the arrays -

```
const arr1Map: ReadonlyMap<string, string | undefined> = new Map(
    arr1.map(
        ({
            name, age, city, address
        }) => [
            `${name}|${age}|${city}`,
            address
        ]
    )
);

const arr2Map: ReadonlyMap<string, string | undefined> = new Map(
    arr2.map(
        ({
            name, age, city, address
        }) => [
            `${name}|${age}|${city}`,
            address
        ]
    )
);
```

Empty arrays -

```
let arr1Match: I[] = []
let arr1Unmatch: I[] = []
let arr2Match: I[] = []
let arr2Unmatch: I[] = []
```

What I need to do now is to campare all values in `arr1` to `arr2`, if there is a match, store the match from `arr1` in `arr1Match` and the match from `arr2` in `arr2Match`. If there is an Unmatch I need to store the unmatch `arr1` in `arr1Unmatch` and the unmatch from `arr2` in `arr2Unmatch`.
And if there is a match I need to store the `address` from `arr2` into `arr1`.

The desierd output -

arr1Match: `[{ name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' }, { name: "kosta", age: 28, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' } ]`

arr2Match: `[{ name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' }, { name: "kosta", age: 28, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' }]`

arr1Unmatch: `[{ name: "yoav", age: 28, city: "NYC" }]`

arr2Unmatch: `[{ name: "simon", age: 24, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' }, { name: "david", age: 22, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' }]`

Comment: What constitutes a match? Either way, you should make a function that checks if 2 values match, then loop over both arrays twice and check each pair of values

Comment: Wasn't this question asked already today? - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857718/array-iteration-inside-array-of-objects)?

Comment: what is with the old answers? what does not fit?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no it's not the same question

Comment: @heyheyhey you're right it's not (silly me), but you definitely already asked this earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on some questions about your needs: What constitutes a match? If there's different data between the matches, what should be put in the match array? Should the arrays point to the original objects, or to copies of them?
Also, it looks like there is no difference between `arr1Match` and `arr2Match`, so those can be combined into one

Either way the solution would be to iterate over one array, and search for a match in the other array for every value. Any item that doesn't match will go to the unmatch arrays

```
// Replace with real match logic
const isMatch = <T>(a: T, b: T) => Math.random() < 0.5;

const getMatches = <T>(arrOne: T[], arrTwo: T[]) => {
  const matches: T[] = [];
  const arrOneUnmatches: T[] = [];
  let arrTwoUnmatches: T[];

  // Copying for comfortability's sake
  const arrTwoCopy = [...arrTwo];

  arrOne.forEach(item => {
    // Find a match in array two
    const arrTwoMatchIndex = arrTwoCopy.findIndex(arrTwoItem => isMatch(item, arrTwoItem));
    if (arrTwoMatchIndex) {
      matches.push(item);

      // Remove it from arrTwoCopy, to maintain arrTwoUnmatches
      arrTwoCopy.splice(arrTwoMatchIndex, 1);
    } else {
      // No match = go to arrOneUnmatches
      arrOneUnmatches.push(item);
    }
  })

  // Anyone left in arrTwoCopy didn't match anyone in arrOne, so they have no match
  arrTwoUnmatches = arrTwoCopy;

  return { matches, arrOneUnmatches, arrTwoUnmatches }
}
```

Comment: There is no assigning of the `address` from `arr2` to `arr1`.

Desired output - arr1Match: `[{ name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' }, { name: "kosta", age: 28, city: "NYC", address: 'E. 43' } ]`

Current output - 

`[
    {
      "name": "daniel",
      "age": 21,
      "city": "NYC"
    },
    {
      "name": "kosta",
      "age": 28,
      "city": "NYC"
    }
  ]`

Comment: @heyheyhey ok? so change it to match your needs. I gave you pretty much all you need